# Facebook based mobile App to access user's FB main page?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-login, mobile-application

I want to develop an FB based mobile application where a user can access into his(her) FB main page thru the mobile app.

Then make a user extract info and surf into his friends FB the main page as well. I wonder how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start with the facebook api for android. It is pretty powerful but it doesn't give you the full level of control that some other web based api's provide. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

```
Facebook Login - Enables authentication with Facebook credentials.
Share and Send dialogs - People can share content from your app to Facebook.
App Events - Log events in your application.
Graph API - Read and write to Graph API << *look here for what you want to do*
```

If this isn't enough, you will want to explore the web and javascript api's which appear to provide more access than the current android api.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript

Note that your app may not be able to access all of the information you want it to access unless your friends have also installed your app and given it the appropriate access permissions.